# nginx: Is it possible to use a map variable in fastcgi_read_timeout

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to do this:

```
map $request_uri $php_timeout {
  default 60s;
  "~^/slow/process/(?:1|two|three)" 120s;
}

...

fastcgi_read_timeout $php_timeout;
```

but `nignx -t` gives an error:

> nginx: [emerg] "fastcgi_read_timeout" directive invalid value in /etc/nginx/...

Is this simply not possible? [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout) don't say it's not (or that it is).

Nb. if it's not clear, I have several URLs that are best described by a set of regex tests that require different timeouts. I could write separate location blocks for all of these but that gets messy.

Comment: May be you should use another `location` for slow scripts

Comment: @AlexeyTen yes it's clear from your answer (thanks!) that I'll have to! Just gets awkward as the slow scripts cross-cut other location definitions. Anyhow, thanks.

Comment: On the other hand, you could just set `120s` for all scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fastcgi_read_timeout` cannot contain variables. Directives that could use variables are marked so.

For example in `fastcgi_param`:

> […] The value can contain text, **variables**, and their combination.